# Run line of Perl/Python/Ruby from Bash

Tags: python, ruby, bash, perl, shell

I want to run a Ruby/Python one-liner in a shell script, like:

```
python 'print "hello world"'
```

or

```
ruby 'puts "hello world"'
```

or something like that so I can quickly pipe the input elsewhere.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each of these commands has a switch to execute a string passed as an argument. For python, it's `-c`:

```
$ python -c 'print "hello world"'
hello world
```

For ruby, it's `-e`:

```
$ ruby -e 'puts "hello world"'
hello world
```

By the way, the output of `python --help`, `ruby --help` or looking in the `man` page for either program would give you the answer.

Answer (score 6):

Since version 2.05b, bash can redirect standard input (stdin) from a "here string" using the `<<<` operator.

```
$ python <<< 'print "hello world"'
hello world
$ ruby <<< 'puts "hello world"'
hello world
```

Comment: One of the only answers with a unique answer. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Use the argument to the interpreter that tells it that the next argument is code to be run.

```
python -c 'print "hello world"'
```

Answer (score 1):

For Ruby:

```
ruby -e 'puts "Hello world"'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you mean using a one liner of perl/awk/python in a pipe, it is just like most other Unix utilities:

```
$ python -c 'print "hello"' | tr "[a-z]" "[A-Z]"
HELLO
$ ruby -e 'puts "hello"' | tr "[a-z]" "[A-Z]"
HELLO
$ python -c 'print "GREETINGS"'  | perl -lpe 's/([EI])/lc($1)/ge'
GReeTiNGS
```

Comment: Seems kinda harsh to vote this down given the votes on the other answers here.

Comment: Printing from Python to pipe to Perl to use regex! :-)

Comment: @sawa: what are you saying? Posts should be judged not just on what they say but what they used to say???

Comment: @thewolf [W]hat are you saying? Votes should foresee the future edit[?]

Comment: I suppose not being one who down votes often I think it does make sense to change the vote if the original reason is no longer there. I personally only down vote if a) the answer is wrong and b) someone does not change it if given a chance.

Answer (score 1):

In Perl, from command line:

```
perl -e 'print "Hello World\n";'
```

Or inside bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

perl -e 'print "Hello World\n";'
```

Comment: You can also save two characters and go `perl -E 'say "Hello World"'`. You don't need the `;` at all. Actually OP was not asking for a line break though.

Answer (score 1):

You need neither Perl, Python or Ruby to pipe a fixed string to another application. The `echo` program can be used for that.

```
$ echo 'foo' | cat
foo
```

See [explainshell.com](http://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=%20echo%20%27foo%27%20%7C%20cat) for more infos.